# I am new to sequelize, how to convert mysql query to sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js

Mysql query:

```
SELECT categories.name AS CATEGORIES,GROUP_CONCAT(subcategories.name) AS 
SUBCATEGORIES FROM subcategories INNER JOIN categories ON 
subcategories.categorieName = categories.name GROUP BY categories.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

For already prepared SQL queries, you can utilize the function `sequelize.query`

You can try:

```
sequelize.query("SELECT categories.name AS CATEGORIES,GROUP_CONCAT(subcategories.name) AS SUBCATEGORIES FROM subcategories INNER JOIN categories ON subcategories.categorieName = categories.name GROUP BY categories.name")
.spread((results, metadata) => {
  // Results will be an empty array
  // and metadata will contain the number of affected rows.
})
```

Your reference, for More details:

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/raw-queries.html

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks Ankit, I know about raw queries but I want sequelize formatted query.  :)